# testlink can not import more than 1131 testcases

Tags: import, testlink

My testlink environment is:
Linux Ubuntu14.04.4 
Apache 2.4.7
Mysql 5.6
php5
TestLink 1.9.17
I tried to import more than 2000 testcases,but it only succeeded import 1131 testcases.and it receive a white page on the right frame on import page.and when I deleted the testsuite,it only delete the  The first three sub testsuites,the fouth sub testsuite is not deleted.

I tried to change max_input_vars = 1000 to max_input_vars = 10000 in php.ini,but still the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I config /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini as follows,and succeed
max_input_vars = 1000 
max_input_vars = 10000 
memorylimit 128M 
memorylimit 256M 
post_max_size 12M 
upload_max_filesize 10M 
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart